# how to save the user account and password with Qwebview

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I load the https://accounts.google.com
with Qwebview ,I wonder how can I save the user account and password at the moment that I  click the log in button ?

Answer (score 1):

That's actually a fairly complicated question -- a few ideas come to mind.

First, and most intrusive, would be to inject some javascript/jQuery code into the webview that would ultimately lead to a signal containing form data for your application to process. You could decide whether it contained a user/pass and, if so, offer to store it.

Another way of doing things (I think) would be to intercept the form submission, but this cannot be done in a `QWebView`, but in a `QWebPage` via the [`acceptNavigationRequest()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qwebpage.html#acceptNavigationRequest) function (this will probably require subclassing `QWebPage`). Once you've done this, you could traverse the DOM with Qt's classes and pull out the necessary form data.

---

**edit after upvote:** I know this is six years out now, but there's a deeper question to address here. *Why do you need to capture a username/password combo?* Most likely you don't, and you definitely shouldn't. Google accounts support authentication via [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). Responsible applications should never ask for a username/password to a foreign account.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a bit late. But it turns out that Qt5 automaticly does this for you. But Qt6 does not. Only tested this py python using PyQt5/PSide2 tho